# ASP.NET Core Identity - Creating user "manually" and providing password hash - How to generate hash correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I must create user manually:

```
var user = new User
{
    Name = "Joe",
    Email = "test@****.com",
    PasswordHash = "gdfgdfgre2132143xcxzvb=="
}

context.Users.Add(user);
```

but the thing is that when I try to log into that account my password doesn't work.

I **copied Password's hash of User account that I know password to** and then I pasted it to that new User and tried to use the same password and it didnt work - `password sign in failed`

So I'd want to ask - what's wrong with my logic here and how can I make it work?

Is it related to SecurityStamp?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to manually add the user , you should also set the `NormalizedUserName` property . In addition , it's better to use `IPasswordHasher<TUser> Interface` for hashing passwords:

The injected services :

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
public readonly IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser> _passwordHasher;

public HomeController( ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser> _passwordHasher)
{

    this._context = dbContext;
    this._passwordHasher = _passwordHasher;

}
```

I assume your `User` inherits `IdentityUser` , here i use `IdentityUser` for example:

```
IdentityUser applicationUser = new IdentityUser();
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
applicationUser.Id = guid.ToString();
applicationUser.UserName = "Joe";
applicationUser.Email = "wx@hotmail.com";
applicationUser.NormalizedUserName = "wx@hotmail.com";

_context.Users.Add(applicationUser);


var hashedPassword = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(applicationUser, "YourPassword");
applicationUser.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
applicationUser.PasswordHash = hashedPassword;

_context.SaveChanges();
```

You can also use `UserManager.CreateAsync` to create the specified user in the backing store with given password :

```
var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = "Joe", Email = "wx@hotmail.com" };
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "YourPassWord");
if (result.Succeeded)
{

}
```

Notice : You should provide `Email` value during login .

Comment: the thing is, that I'm creating this account in tests and injecting all those REAL Identity related classes is painful for me

Comment: Then you can use the manually way , provider related properties .

Comment: Thanks! Apparently creating an instance of PasswordHasher didnt require any other dependencies - everything works fine!