# Create an IdentityUser by context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating an `IdentityUser` through the Identity context, using `OnModelCreating`, but I'm having problems passing the password, as it must be encrypted.

Here is the code where I create the user:

```
builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasData(new IdentityUser { Id= "0CD0E173758F4492B41EDD4A51D36BA5", UserName = "admin@admin.com", Email = "admin@admin.com",EmailConfirmed = true });
```

I would like to know how I can pass the password, because I need to login to this user.

Comment: The answer you're looking for has been already answered somewhere else on StackOverFlow, refer to this
[StackOverFlow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58180234/asp-net-core-identity-creating-user-manually-and-providing-password-hash-h)

Comment: The attached link doesn't have my solution because I'm adding it directly in the context, and there I can't be using the `userManager`.

Comment: Not the best approach. Seed user using userManager [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58180596/10302096) will be more elegant way to achieve your goal

Comment: But should I create this default user where? If you create in the controller's constructor, wouldn't the creation code be run whenever the code was initialized, thus creating this user more than once?

Comment: Hi,@Douglas Badaró,Have you tried with PasswordHasher<TUser> to generate the password hash